# Is it possible to auto-update Electron apps without a certificate?

Tags: certificate, electron

I made an Electron app and want to setup auto-updating on Windows and macOS. The problem is that electron-updater requires a certificate, and I don't have the money to get a certificate. Is there a way to set up electron-updater without a certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a certificate, it can be done under Windows environment only, not macOS.

Comment: Do you mean macOS?

Comment: Yes, I mean macOS must have certificate. Here is example for windows (without certificate): https://github.com/Longfld/electron-angular-material

Comment: Also Linux (with AppImage builds).

Comment: Can you show/share some article/reference to distribute Electron Window's build and apply auto update and Install from S3?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by removing *win* section and fields named *certificateFile* and *certificatePassword* under win section from *package.json*.

```
 "build": {
   "squirrelWindows": {
    }
 }
```

All examples includes certificate files and you may consider that they are required however it will build without certificate file.

But at the end of they day, you will have issues with unsigned codes.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can, take a look on this one [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)

I use it for a complete build of my app, and also you can setup [auto update](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Auto-Update)

Hope this will help.

Comment: `For macOS, you will need a code-signing certificate.` 
 https://github.com/iffy/electron-updater-example

Comment: @AliSaeed You can use it without, macOS will notify you that this is dangerous to use this app.

Comment: Great, can you show me how? I keep getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Could not get code signature for running application` at the line `autoUpdater.setFeedUrl(..)` if I don't have it certificate code-signed.

Comment: @AliSaeed is it your prod build ? or how you run your app ? looks like you trying to run it locally with the cli ?

Comment: Without a certificate, auto updates will not run on macOS. You at least need a self-signed cert that you specify as trusted from your keychain.